# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list with 3 parameters

Tags: javascript, asp.net, javascript-databinding

```
<a id='aApp' runat='server' title='Approve' onclick='return OpenAppWin("<%#Eval("ID1") %>",
"<%#Eval("ID2") %>","<%#Eval("NAME") %>")' class='label' href='#'>Approve</a>
```

I need to pass 3 parameters as querystring to iframe, reason I am using runat='server' with anchor is to show user they can't click this link until they submit "remarks" which I am doing at server side i.e. disable link. Onclick I get this error Please advice any alternative or how to fix this error ?

Comment: use `ctrl+k` for proper formatting of code.

Comment: Which error thrown when the anchor link being clicked? Also how `OpenAppWin` method defined?

Comment: ctrl+k+d works for formatting code on VS2008, but that's not the issue exactly, its a simple Jscript function with 3 param.  I can run the code but error comes when I click link

Comment: error is : SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
 

return OpenAppWin("<%#Eval("ID1") %>","<%#Eval("ID2") %>","<%#Eval("NA...

Comment: function OpenAppWin(ID1, ID2, name) {
                var oWnd;
                oWnd = $find('<%= mdlPopApprove.ClientID %>');
                if (ID1 != '' && oWnd != null) {

                    oWnd.setUrl("../ContextMenus/Approve.aspx?ID=" + ID1 + "&PLID=" + ID2 + "&PL=" + name);
                    oWnd.add_close(OnWindowClose);
                    oWnd.show();
                }
            }   @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Seems that one of the `Eval` method in `return OpenAppWin("<%# Eval("ID1") %>", "<%# Eval("ID2") %>", "<%# Eval("NAME") %>")` interpreted as plain string instead of giving ID, hence throwing JS syntax error. Can you give detail how `ID1`, `ID2` & `NAME` passed to page from code-behind?

Comment: ID1,ID2 & NAME are Datakeynames from Grid- @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are enclosing double quotes withing double quote, using single and double quotes combination to avoid that.

```
onclick="return OpenAppWin('<%#Eval("ID1")%>','<%#Eval("ID2") %>','<%#Eval("NAME") %>');"
```

**Edit** based on comments, binding javascript event on server side

Bind javascript event in RowDataBound event on server side.

```
void gridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
      HyperLink link = (HyperLink)e.FindControl("aApp");
      link.Attribute.Add("onclick", ="return OpenAppWin('"+ DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID1") + "','" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID2") + "', '" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Name") + "');"
  }
}
```

Comment: got this error on trying above syntax   Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Comment: Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed. @Adil

Comment: Yes I did, @Adil.

Comment: when working with without runat='server' it works. but my requirement is to disable link server side based on condition. @Adil

Comment: If it is server side then try to bind event on RowDataBound event

Comment: Good to know you did it!.